How close can supersonic airplanes get to subsonic fuel efficiencies?
I was struck by this sentence in @therac's excellent answer for why quieter supersonic planes don't offer efficiency gains.

Supersonic L/D will always be lower than subsonic, like a best-case of 7:1 vs 20:1. So it will always consume a lot more fuel and cost more.

Are there efficiency gains with quiet supersonic technology?
It made me wonder how much of the higher drag is made up by traveling at a higher speed? For example if drag is three times higher at three times the velocity, overall fuel consumption should be similar burning fuel at three times the rate for a trip that only takes one third as long.
So my main question is, how big is this effect and how close has any supersonic plane ever got to subsonic fuel efficiency while flying supersonic? Specifically what triggered this question is I wonder how the B-70 Valkyrie achieved such a relatively long range despite its extremely high cruising speed.

You are partially right - if thrust-specific fuel consumption (TSFC) was the same, a L:D of 7 at average Mach 2.0 would bring the same burn per mile as a L:D of 20 at Mach 0.7.
The tie-breaker is that TSFC is generally higher for supersonic-capable engines, and for these engines, is again higher at supersonic speed than at subsonic. The Concorde's engines have been addressed in detail.
Even being relatively efficient, they consumed ~2x the fuel per pound thrust compared to a subsonic turbofan at subsonic speed.
So there's two things making supersonic fuel economy worse:

Lower L/D
Higher TSFC

Versus one making it better - higher speed.
Overall, for Concorde vs conventional airliner, you get 3x worse L/D, 2x worse TSFC, but 2.5x higher speed, resulting in ~6/2.5 ~= 2.4x worse fuel burn per ton-mile. Thus, fuel economy still favors subsonic aircraft.


How close can supersonic airplanes get to subsonic fuel efficiencies?

Depends on how you define efficiency. If you mean transporting the same people from point A to point B then the answer is simply: not even remotely close.
Flying supersonic has mainly two big disadvantages in respect to flying subsonic:

the need of a stronger airframe to deal with the high skin temperatures which soften the structure; and
the need of a very big delta wing in order to minimise wave drag.

Even just for these simple reasons, a supersonic airframe is going to be heavier (and therefore less efficient) than an equivalent subsonic design. And once we add wave drag to the picture, the game for the supersonic airplane is irremediably lost. Just for a quick and dirty comparison:

Concorde could carry 120 passengers for 7,200 km (4,400 mi) burning 95,000kg (211,000lb) kerosene (which took up more than 50% of its MTOW); her empty weight was 78,700kg (173,504 lb);
An Airbus A319 can carry a bit more passengers on more or less the same range burning only 24,000kg (53,000lb) kerosene (some 30% of its MTOW); its empty weight is 40,800kg (90,000 lb)

The ratio of their empty weights is around 0.5 while the ratio of their fuel consumption is 0.25: that means that a supersonic airplane must carry around twice as much airframe than an equivalent subsonic design, burning four times as much fuel. These ratios are simply unbeatable.

I wonder how the B-70 Valkyrie achieved such a relatively long range

No wonder rather a lot of kerosene: 60% of the MTOW to be precise, i.e.
140,000kg out of 245,000kg.

Perhaps that's why they tried to bring straight wings through the sound barrier in 1947.

No. The power consumed by drag is equal to the drag force times the velocity. At three times the speed and three times the drag, the airplane will consume fuel at nine times the rate.

For jet aircraft, the fuel low (pounds per hour) is generally considered to be proportional to the thrust -- not the power.
So if L/D is 1/3, then 3x the drag is true -- but, you cover ground 3x as fast, so you burn that fuel for 1/3 the time.  Those two cancel out.
However, you aren't going to cruise at Mach 3 at the same TSFC as you would subsonically, so your big penalty is there.

@Rob that’s generally true for a specific engine, but those designed for higher speed flight necessarily have higher exhaust velocity and so are more or less doomed to be less efficient at any speed.

@RobMcDonald You can't beat physics. Going three times faster with three times the drag takes 9 times the mechanical power. You can't get more power out than the energy of the fuel you put in. Turbojet engines mask this by being tremendously inefficient at low speeds, not by magically producing more energy for the same amount of fuel without limit.

@Frog -- yes, the difference in efficiency of higher speed engines is captured in the  change in the TSFC -- thrust specific fuel consumption -- lbm/lbf/hr

@Chris I'm well aware of the physics.  You also can't handwave it when it needs to be written down.  Look at the standard Range equation $R=(V/TSFC)(L/D) ln(Wi/Wf)$.  3x the velocity cancels with 1/3 the L/D.  The difference for these kinds of systems is in the TSFC.  Strange as it seems, the efficiency of converting the heating value of fuel to propulsive power increases with Mach number.

Because ram air drives the compressor more and more.

@RobMcDonald You tacitly assume TSFC is not a function of the airspeed it is meant to operate at. You can't slap a jet engine designed to operate at mach .9 on an aircraft going mach 2.7 and expect it will still work, much less produce the same thrust for the same amount of fuel.

@Chris I certainly do not.  I explicitly state that the variation we see is due to variations of TSFC.  If we were to re-derive the range equation in terms of power specific fuel consumption PSFC, then the velocity would drop from the equation and you would only see the L/D penalty.  However, PSFC is not as useful for jet-thrust kinds of engines as it varies substantially more.  TSFC is relatively constant over a reasonable operating range for a given engine type -- I agree that it is very different say between a HBPR TFan and a Scramjet.

In the drag equation, speed appears with a $^2$ so that the power dissipated due to drag goes with the $^3$ of the speed: at three times the speed, power due to drag is going to be 27 times higher, not 9.
